# Validator controls in ASP.NET usage incase Javascript in the browser is disabled

Tags: javascript, asp.net

why can't we use Javascript instead of using Validator server ASP.net controls like "RequiredFieldValidator" ? Because Javacript runs on the browser and it is faster than ASP.NET server validator controls (thats what i understood so far).

But I read that some users disable Javascript in their browsers. If they do, then the javascript for validations won't execute. Thats why we need to use server validator controls. Is that right?

Comment: Are you talking web forms? If so the Asp.net validator controls validate by using client and server-side validation. Javascript is executed first, with additional serverside checking taking place in case javascript is disabled. If using the ASP.net custom validation control, you can write client-side javascript as well as server side-validation. Taking your example of "RequiredFieldValidator", there is a client-side script that will fire first. There will be no post back if javascript is enabled.

Comment: What Jon P said. also it is *very* rare that users disable js.